# Rspec/FactoryGirl: NoMethodError: undefined method 'description' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

exchange *communidad*. I am trying to write a feature test for my RoR program, but am getting the following error when I run `rspec`:

```
 Failure/Error: page.should have_content entry.description
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `description' for true:TrueClass
```

Here is the context in which the error is being thrown:

```
   entries.each do |entry|
     page.should have_content entry.description

  end
```

where `entries` is defined earlier in the same test as follows:

```
   entries = 5.times.map do

     FactoryGirl.create(:entry, project_id: proj.id, :date => 9/10/13, :type_of_work => 'chump', :description => 'chumpin',
                       :phase => 'Draft', :status => 'Draft' , :on_off_site => 'off', :user_id  => 1, :start_time => now,
                       :end_time =>  later).should be_valid
   end
```

`Entry` is a model which has an attribute of type string called `description` which is what I am testing against and what is returning the true:TrueClass nonsense.

Any leads? Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating entry records via FactoryGirl you are using "should be_valid" method which is returning a boolean object.
So, in entries array, you have only boolean values.

```
entries = [true,true,true,true,true]
```

Thats why its giving error:

```
undefined method `description' for true:TrueClass
```

You should get array of active_records in entries variable. Try this code:

```
entries = 5.times.map do

 entry = FactoryGirl.create(:entry, project_id: proj.id, :date => 9/10/13, :type_of_work => 'chump', :description => 'chumpin',
                   :phase => 'Draft', :status => 'Draft' , :on_off_site => 'off', :user_id  => 1, :start_time => now,
                   :end_time =>  later)
  entry.should be_valid
  entry 
end
```

It will return an active_record array and then you can use all the related methods.

Comment: Thank you so much. I foolishly didn't see that `.should be valid` in the `do` block which I clearly copied from another section of code and didn't realize it was executing that every time.